# Restricting re.findall for number of words in quotation

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get only the quotation out of a sentence - but! only if it's one or two words long. So for the sentence

```py
mysentence = 'Kids, you "tried your best" and you failed miserably. The "lesson" is, "never try."'
```

The output should be

lesson

never try

So far I've got

```py
import re
print(re.findall(r'"(.*?)"', mysentence))
```

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: `r'"[^"\w]*(\w+(?:[^"\w]+\w+)?)[^"\w]*"'`? Check https://regex101.com/r/vjOHb4/2

Comment: If it were 'kids, "you" tried "your" best' it would give me the tried

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/vjOHb4/4, my first suggestion in the answer.

Comment: Ok, so do you allow only spaces or any other punctuation in between the words inside `"..."`?

Comment: `r'"((?:\w+[ .]?){1,2})"'` space and dot as delimer of the words

Comment: it can be any other punctuation like "..." between two words

Comment: Yes. `"((?:\w+[ .]*){1,2})"`. `[ .]*` is punctuation. Now it's "any ammount of spaces and dots. you can also add commas, for example. https://regex101.com/r/XEHNZj/2

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

```
"[^"\s]+(?:\s[^"\s]+)?"
```

The `"` at the start and end matches the quotes beginning end ending the quoted word/phrase. and then we match one word: `[^" ]+`. `[^" ]` is any character that is not a quote or a space. I excluded spaces to make sure that this only matches a single word.

The next part is all in an optional group, because the second word is optional. The second word is a space followed by a single word: `\s[^"\s]+`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/e6S6sD/2)

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
"[^"\s\w]*(\w+(?:\s+\w+)?)[^"\s\w]*"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NMkiil/1).

**Details**

- `"` - a `"` char
- `[^"\s\w]*` - 0+ non-word and non-whitespace chars other than `"`
- `(\w+(?:\s+\w+)?)` - Group 1:

  - `\w+` - 1+ word chars
  - `(?:\s+\w+)?` - an optional sequence of 1+ whitespace chars followed with 1+ word chars
- `[^"\s\w]*` - 0+ non-word and non-whitespace chars other than `"`
- `"` - a `"` char

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/RwD5by):

```
import re
rx = r'"[^"\s\w]*(\w+(?:\s+\w+)?)[^"\s\w]*"'
s = 'Kids, you "tried your best" and you failed miserably. The "lesson" is, "never try."'
print( re.findall(rx, s) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"((?:\w+[ .]*){1,2})"
```

You can easily change necessary number of words to match by changing `2` to proper number.

[See the demo](https://regex101.com/r/XEHNZj/2).

- `"` - a `"` char
- `((?:\w+[ .]*){1,2})` - Group 1:

  - `(?:\w+[ .]*)` - non-capturing group

    - `\w+` - sequence of 1+ 'word' chars
    - `[ .]*` - optional chars set for word delimiter. In our case spaces and dots.
  - `{1,2}` - number of repeating 'from one to two' of non-capturing group
- `"` - a `"` char

As variant, for word separators can be described as "0+ sequence of not a word char and not a `"` char". Like this `[^"\w]*`

For example:

```
"((?:\w+[^"]*){1,2})"
```

[See the demo](https://regex101.com/r/XEHNZj/4)